# How do I embed my custom Google map into Wordpress, focused on a specific location?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have a custom Google map that has various different locations marked onto it.

I would like to embed the map in various Wordpress posts, and have each post zoomed into each different marker on the map.

Right now, I can embed the map, but it is fully zoomed out.

Can I customise the embed code? eg. Can I input coordinates and zoom level?

[googlemaps https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXk&w=640&h=480]

Answer (score 0):

I think that response your question, yo can add a zoom and other parameters. The documentation and example is here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters

Your url must be similar to this:
"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=16&center=25.6707%2C-100.3081&key=XXXX"